# Converting .htaccess to nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

The following is the .htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I used winginx to the get nginx rewrite which is,

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
```

But it not working the desired.

The original URL is: http://xxxx/foo/info/getinfo/123/

The converted URL should be:
http://xxx/foo/index.php?url=info/getinfo/123/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Changed it to the following

```
rewrite ^/foo/(.*)$ /foo/index.php?url=$1 break;
```